# Calculating a limit using the Squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus

I have shown using the binomial expansion that

$2^n > \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

My question is how can I use this fact along with the squeeze theorem to find

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your identity you get, for $n\ge3$,
$$
0<\frac1{2^n}<\frac{3!}{n(n-1)(n-2)}
$$ giving, for $n\ge3$,
$$
0<\frac{n^2}{2^n}<\frac{3!\cdot n^2}{n(n-1)(n-2)}=\frac{6}{(n-1)(1-\frac2n)}
$$ then you can conclude as $n \to \infty$.